# Align vertical text next to the image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create exactly like what is shown in the picture below. So far, it's not looking good for me.

[image]

Here's the JSFiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/6o3nz6g9/**

HTML:

```
<h1>This is Sparta!</h1>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.services__text {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right top 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: right top 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0;
    transform-origin: right top 0;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

How do I do to get this desired effect? FYI: I'm working on Bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change positioning of `.services__text` and then using `translate` align that before `image`.

```css
.services__text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-40%, -200%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is Sparta!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The alignment is off when the title is longer than 'Title Text Here'. And when it's shorter.

Comment: @AJMaxwell Check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yLvvnr56/, that's true need to add width to .service__text so that it keeps text in same position and can add as long as needed, but I have added overflow as hidden in parent element so when you scale in provided jsFiddle you will see that some portion of text is hidden, so to get that to same position at certain screen resolution OP needs to use media query. Now there were two ways to do this either negative left or translate as suggest. Mostly translate works fine on rotated elements.

Answer (score 2):

**Hey Champ, You may solve your problem with following CSS**

```css
.services__text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1>This is Sparta!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="services__text">Title Text Here</div>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hccDVF/sample.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following css properties in your code for class `.service_text`

```
top:20px;  left:-126px;  position:absolute;
```

And add a class to your `class="col-xs-4"` as `class="col-xs-4 parent"`
And for `parent` add following css. `position: relative;    padding-left: 8px;`

**This will give exactly same result. And if you want further explanation i would love to help you on that**

Answer (score 1):

This method will work with any length of text (so long as it's a single line).

```
.services__text {
    position:absolute;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width:100%;
    left:-8px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

- `translate(-100%)` moves the elements new position -100% of its width to its left (down).
- `width:100%;` gives your title room to expand. This the elements *height*.
- `text-align:right;` pushes the text to the *top* of the image
- `position:absolute;` & `left:-8px;` pushes the text to the outside of the image (possibly overlapping other elements)